# How Can I Use Kitto (/Dashing) With A Standard React Fetch API?

Tags: reactjs, elixir, dashboard

The Short Story:
How does Elixir/Kitto link its Ruby syntax with the React parts?

Context:
Hi there. I'm a newbie in a React-heavy dev team while from a non dev background - so still finding my feet, as you can imagine.

I've been asked to build a dashboard that uses API live-feed/data - using React. I imagined this as a cloud hosted app that uses fetch to get api data through and displays in React components.

We found Kitto online, it looks rather great.
https://github.com/kittoframework/kitto

But... here's the challenge: code-wise, a lot of it appears very *very* Ruby-like (though the components are React).

So i'm very confused. How can i use Kitto as a slick React dashboard, but fetch my api data in a React 'fetch' fashion, if a lot of the logic is in Ruby? Or something very similar?

**Or more specifically:**
How do the .html.eex Elixir files talk to the api / React components?

Comment: Elixir looks like Ruby, but is not Ruby FYI.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions at the Kitto site?  If so, what's happening that leads you to believe there's an issue?

Comment: Thanks Onorio and David - I have followed Kitto's instructions. They get your sample doc up and running but to know the intricacies of how to implement api data and have Elixir talk to React is left unexplained. 
Have either of you configured a Kitto/Elixir dashboard at all? :)

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci meant to tag you both there.